# Deleting comments in MVC view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to include html-comment in my view (mvc3-app):

```
<!-- comment -->
```

but Razor delete this code on render page. I try to use

```
@Html.Raw ("<!-- Comment -->")
```

but without result.

p.s. i need to use comment for google-adsense targeting.

**edited:**
Add Html.Raw result

Left side -> VS code. Right side -> FireBug

[image: Html.Raw]

Comment: try this :
`string c = "<!-- Comment -->";
@Html.Raw(c)`

Comment: What exactly didn't work with using Html.Raw?

Comment: JaceRhea, exactly. All html-code work, but not html-comments

Comment: What are you using to view the markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor view engine deletes from resulting markup 'server-side' comments within a `@* ... *@` block, but it keeps 'client-side' comments (i.e. HTML comments) - `<!-- ... -->`.

They can be deleted by your browser markup viewer. Try to open full page markup or view it in another tool.